# AssertionError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken. Python Django

Tags: python, django

When trying to check the form of validity `if _dict['form'].is_valid()`gives an error message
`AssertionError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.`

I understand that the error in `phone = ChoiceTxtField(queryset=Clients.objects.order_by('-phone')[:1])` in forms.py. How to avoid this error when adding a form?

**some.py**

```
def checkRelatedAddForm(self, **kwargs):
    context= {}
    request_post = kwargs['request_post']
    related_form = RelatedAddForm(request_post, prefix=self.prefix)
    related_form.prefix = self.prefix
    context['form'] = related_form        
    if related_form.is_valid():
                #some code
            else:
                #some code 2
    #ERROR AssertionError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken
    return context
```

**forms.py**

```
class ListTextWidget(forms.Select):
    template_name = 'include/_forms_clients_datalist.html'

    def format_value(self, value):
        if value == '' or value is None:
            return ''
        if self.is_localized:
            return formats.localize_input(value)
        return str(value)

    class ChoiceTxtField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
        widget=ListTextWidget()
    
    class RelatedAddForm(forms.ModelForm):   
        phone = ChoiceTxtField(queryset=Clients.objects.order_by('-phone')[:1]) #
    
        class Meta:
            model = Clients
            fields = ['name', 'phone']
            widgets = {
                'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
            }
```

**include/_forms_clients_datalist.html**

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ajax_phone_{{ widget.name }}').keyup(function () {
                // create an AJAX call
                $.ajax({
                    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                    url: "{% url 'ajax_request' %}?related=clients&data={{ widget.name }}",
                    // on success
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.is_exist == true) {
                            $("#ajax-{{ widget.name }}").text(response.is_taken.name);
                            var dataList = document.getElementById('{{ widget.name }}');
                            var input = document.getElementById('ajax_phone_{{ widget.name }}');
                            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            document.getElementById('{{ widget.name }}').innerHTML = '';
                            response.is_taken.forEach(function(item) {
                                    console.log(item)
                                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                                    option.value = item.id;
                                    option.title = item.name;
                                    option.text = item.phone;
                                    dataList.appendChild(option);
                                  });
                            }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(response.responseJSON.errors)
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
                $('#ajax_phone_{{ widget.name }}').on('change', function(){
                $("#ajax-{{ widget.name }}").text($('#'+$(this).attr('list')).find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').text());
                var opt = $('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]');
                $('#id_clients-name').val(opt.length ? opt.attr('title') : 'No phone')
            });
})

    </script>
{% endblock javascript %}
<br>
<input id="ajax_phone_{{ widget.name }}" list="{{ widget.name }}"
    {% if widget.value != None %} name="{{ widget.name }}" value="+7" {% endif %}
    {% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %} autocomplete="off">
    <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-warning text-dark" id="ajax-{{ widget.name }}" name="ajax-{{ widget.name }}"></span>

<datalist id="{{ widget.name }}">
</datalist><br>
```

Comment: Why do you have such an unusual queryset that is limited to one Client? To avoid the error you need to, well, remove the slice, but it's impossible to tell why/how without understanding the point

Comment: ошибка в ChoiceTxtField в form, если убираю queryset, все отлично

Comment: Please stick to English. Yes, the issue with ChoiceTxtField. Why do you have a queryset with `.order_by('-phone')[:1]` there? It will limit the field to only one choice and does not make sense.

Comment: I have a datalist in forms_clients_datalist.html where this queryset is being output. If I remove the queryset, then it says that this is a required parameter for the ChoiceTxtField. How to be?

Comment: Why the slice (`[:1]`) though?  If you remove it, it will work.